# In the s1 finale, who is Miku talking to on the phone?

Tags: the-quintessential-quintuplets

I'm asking because we see that Miku is talking on the phone with either Itsuki or Ichika. Who is it?

> [image]

We know (s1 spoiler)

> Itsuki impersonates Ichika but not really (at least in the anime) specifically when and to what extent. I'm not sure if Ichika actually did go out skiing for a bit. Did Itsuki impersonate to the extent of stealing Ichika's phone?

Is it perhaps clarified in the manga?

**Guesses**: (s1 spoiler)

> 1. It really is Ichika who temporarily went out of the cabin.

> 2. It is actually Itsuki who somehow got ahold of Ichika's phone and is impersonating Ichika *even* on the phone besides in person.

> 3. It is Ichika on the phone but the person on the right hand side is Itsuki...who is for some reason making a separate phone call at precisely the same time.

> 4. Much like in (Higurashi/)Umineko, the scene on the right hand side *did not happen*. But then please explain...did Itsuki steal Ichika's phone and then answer while outside the doorway of Ichika's room? (Or inside the room but Ichika was asleep?) Or what?

> 5. Other?

Comment: Just to confirm: did you watch this episode and the next without skipping anything? If yes, then I am not sure how this information was missed. If not, I suggest re-watching the episodes. Did you also try looking this up or maybe checking the manga?

Comment: @W.Are Edited post. I watched all s1 and s2. I looked it up on fandom. Couldn't find anything. Didn't check manga because I suspect it would be a huge wheel reinvention to check. I actually watched all s1 and s2 sub and I'm now rewatching the series dubbed. Currently midway s2. I thought I would get this in a rewatch, but well, I didn't, so here I am. In fact, this kind of question I think is something you formulate precisely from a rewatch. We know Itsuki impersonates Ichika but not really specifically when and to what extent. Thanks for commenting. Happy Easter.

Comment: The question is asking who Miku is talking to. Your answer is talking about a guess on what happened in the episode and did not mention who Miku was talking to. Please clarify what you really wanted to know. What I think happened: it was Ichika that Miku was talking to due to the fact that she called the MC by his first name during the call (Itsuki calls him by his given name). Manga is a bit unclear but in the anime, it showed that Ichika was outside when Miku made the call. When she went out, when she went back in, it was not really mentioned.

Comment: @W.Are Thanks. Edited answer to be explicit. It's during step 2 that Ichika talks to Miku. 1 - Is there anything wrong with my answer? 2 - By 'given name' do you mean instead 'last name' ?

Comment: 1. Others may have different interpretation or there may have been details we missed but I think this is correct. Advice: in future answers, try to elaborate and provide references, if possible. 2. Yes. I meant to say family name or the last name.

Comment: @W.Are Ok thanks. Feel free to post this as an answer or copy my answer as your own and then I'll delete mine and upvote and accept yours.

Comment: Self-answering and accepting own answers to own questions is completely fine and isn't against the rules.

Comment: @W.Are Yeah, but I wanna give you the points as a proper thank you. It's up to you.

Comment: @W.Are So it's just convenient that Itsuki wasn't caught impersonating Ichika during the time Ichika went out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I understand.

1. Itsuki went out impersonating Ichika (the '[Uesugi-kun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC5V1.jpg)' part) and then
2. **Ichika ALSO went out** (during this Ichika talks to Miku) but then later
3. **Ichika went back in** and
4. Itsuki was still impersonating Ichika, and **Itsuki really hadn't been caught impersonating** because when Ichika went out, Ichika hadn't run into the other quints or something.

**What I don't quite buy is A - that Ichika indeed went out and then just went back in.** This sounds like a really weird [overanalytical](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4509/is-it-ok-to-overanalyze-an-anime) Higurashi/Umineko kind of explanation like when a culprit steals a key and then later returns it or something. **And B - That Itsuki somehow wasn't caught.**